# Easy check what keybindings are used in Sublime Text editor?

Tags: sublimetext2, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Installed the Sublime Text editor and added "Preferences -> Key Bindings" like this:

`{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+r"], "command": "reindent" , "args": { "single_line": false } }`

Now, how can I be absolutely sure this binding is not already present? 
Since other Sublime Text plugins also create bindings that I cannot find inside "Preferences -> Key Bindings" section looks like the only way is to read help files for Sublime Text plugins. Is there any better way?

Comment: This Sublime Text package might be what you are looking for: [Keybinding​Helper](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/KeybindingHelper). But having read the README I'm still not exactly sure what it does.

Comment: @mattst it shows the commands, which are executed. With this one could press a keybinding and check whether a command is executed or not. However if a keybinding is bound to a scope this technic does not work.

Comment: @r-stein I see, thanks. I too would quite like a plugin which lists all your keybindings (regardless of scope, but including scope info.). I think prosti might still find Keybinding​Helper useful.

Comment: @mattst the [Keymaps](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Keymaps) package can create a cheatsheet of all keybinding, but without the scopes.